# rsync copies everything

Tags: rsync, backup

I'm using rsync to back up my filesystem to a mounted disk `/media/<user>/UbuntuBackups1/`.

I want 6 daily backups, 3 weekly backups and 3 monthly backups if possible.

I've read that by default `rsync` is only supposed to copy new or changed files but that hasn't been my experience. I also want the files accessible from a Windows machine if possible and I have reviewed the man pages and several questions across the web.

I've tried swapping the t flag for the c flag. I've tried omitting -a and adding the included options manually. Every time I run my scripts it copies everything again.

Flags last tested were checksums only, verbose, recurse into directories, ownership, groups, permissions.

It also has on at least one occasion, copied all the exclusions as well.

I'm putting scripts in cron.daily and cron.weekly if that makes a difference.

```
rsync -cvrogp --links --exclude=/dev --exclude=/mnt --exclude=/media --exclude=/tmp --exclude=/lost+found --exclude=/emby --exclude=/cloud --exclude=/home/_myuser_/.cache --exclude=/proc --exclude=/run --exclude=/sys / /media/_myuser_/UbuntuBackups1/daily
```

I see I can use logrotate for handling the versions so `nvm` that we'll just stick to rsync for now.

Comment: What filesystem is used in `/media/_myuser_/UbuntuBackups1/daily`?

Comment: Add the `-i` flag and you'll get additional output.  Add a few lines of it to your question.

Comment: @ArkadiuszDrabczyk fuseblk is the fstype reported by df -Th

Comment: @BowlOfRed 
`.f...p..... lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/vp27smpx.ko
.f...p..... lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/vpx3220.ko
.f...p..... lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/wm8739.ko
.f...p..... lib/modules/4.15.0-88-generic/kernel/drivers/media/i2c/wm8775.ko`

Comment: @JeffreyBecker: fuseblk is NTFS AFAIK, that may be the reason. Check if your `rsync` command works correctly by using it on non-NTFS filesystem, `ext3` or something. You can for example create a temporary directory in `/tmp`, say `/tmp/rsync`, create several files there `touch a b c d`, create a new directory `/tm/rsync-test` in which you could try to mirror `/tmp/rsync`. Run `rsync` again, then create new files in `/tmp/rsync` and check if only new files are copied. It should work.

Comment: @JeffreyBecker, it's better to edit that into your question rather than put it in a comment.  It's easier to see the info all at once for someone examining it.

Answer (score 0):

Your string is saying that the permissions are not matched between the copies.  It's not copying the file, but it is trying to reset the permissions.

As your destination is NTFS, the permssions are probably not mapped identically.  You might want to try `--no-perms`